# Error mounting NFS unit between synology server and Raspberry Pi client

Tags: networking, nas, iptables, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS (v4, or v3.. but get the same error...) from a Synology Server to a Raspberry Pi client. But I get this error:

```
mount -t nfs4 IP_address_of_server:/volume1/nfsnvf /mnt/nfsnvf
mount.nfs4: Connection timed out
```

If I try with the `showmount` command, get this error:

```
showmount -e IP_address_of_server
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 113 (No route to host)
```

I have a Synology Server in a corporate network (behind a router): - Ports open in this router: TCP/2049, UDP/2049, TCP/111 and UDP/111 - IPTables list of the Synology Server:

```
DiskStationV5> iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DEFAULT_INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DEFAULT_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DEFAULT_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports sunrpc,892,nfs
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports sunrpc,892,nfs
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DEFAULT_INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports sunrpc,892,nfs
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports sunrpc,892,nfs
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Then in another corporative network I have a RaspberryPi (behind another router). - Ports open in this network: TCP/2049, UDP/2049.

Also, the `/etc/export` generated by synology is this:

```
/volume1/nfsnvf
*(rw,async,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
```

Any idea about where can be the problem?

Comment: Try pinging/traceroute. If the error message is really “No route to host”, it’s not a firewall problem at all, but a routing problem. In that case, please share the actual IP addresses and your routing table.

Comment: Thanks, after solving that part (an error with the default gateway!), now the problem is this one:

mount -t nfs IP_address_of_server:/volume1/nfsnvf /mnt/nfsnvf

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

And if i use the following command:

mount -t nfs4 IP_address_of_server:/volume1/nfsnvf /mnt/nfsnvf

Get that error:

mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the current state of affairs.